# Custom Bootstrap-Vue checkbox component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I’m trying to make components to create a dynamic form but I’m having trouble with checkboxes

```
<template v-if="type === 'switch'">
            <b-form-checkbox
                switch
                size="lg"
                :name="name"
                :id="name"
                :ref="name"
                :value="value"
                v-on:input.native="updateValue($event.target.value)"
                >{{ value }}</b-form-checkbox
            >
        </template>
```

Here's how I call the code

```
<FormRow
                type="switch"
                name="productor"
                rule="required"
                v-model="selectedCompany.productor"
            />
```

The problem is that the `v-model` content doesn't change but it does with input fields. What’s wrong? Can someone help me?

p.s. I’m working with bootstrap-vue
Thank you!

Comment: These can be used different ways.  What did you expect `value` to be checked and unchecked?  And could you show `updateValue`?

Comment: updateValue: function(value) {
            this.$emit("input", value);
        }

Comment: I still don't know what you expect value to be.  true / false?

Comment: I expect the status of the checkbox, so true if checkbox is set, false if is unchecked. The problem is that right now it starts with empy, then i set to true and i works but when i switch back to false it remains true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `v-model` on the checkbox.  Remove the `value` attribute and the `input` listener and use `v-model` with a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) to elegantly reuse the prop value from the parent as the model without mutating it:

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  switch
  size="lg"
  :name="name"
  :id="name"
  :ref="name"
  v-model="bvalue"
>{{ value }}
</b-form-checkbox>
```

```js
computed: {
  bvalue: {
    get() { return this.value },
    set(value) { this.$emit('input', value) }
  }
}
```

You can remove the `updateValue` method too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this infos can help:
I get the data from the store where i set the state of **selectedCompany: {}**,
then from the parent component (modal) I draw the fields in this way

```
 <FormRow
 type="switch"
 name="productor"
 rule="required"
 v-model="selectedCompany.productor"
 />
```

in the parent I do the following:

```
 <template v-if="type === 'switch'">
     <b-form-checkbox
         switch
         size="lg"
         :name="name"
         :id="name"
         :ref="name"
         :value="value"
         :checked="value"
         v-on:change.native="updateValue($event.target.value)"
         >{{ value }}</b-form-checkbox
    >
  </template>

methods: {
    updateValue: function(value) {
        this.$emit("input", value);
    }
},
```

In the migration file i set the field productor as boolean with default(0) and in the model i mutate the field in this way

```
 public function getProductorAttribute($value){
    return $value ? true : false;
}
```

Everything should be more clear now

Comment: The initial value won't be set properly if you do this.  For example if the parent's value starts as `true`, the checkbox will not reflect it.